# Add node to XML without copying xmlns="" attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

Well, I have this XML

***XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Built using IBM Image Construction and Composition Tool, version: 1.2.0.1-20121129-1310-255 on: Oct 18, 2013 12:14:22 -->
<Envelope
    xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1"
    xmlns:cloudburst="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/rainmaker/2009/3" xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData"
    xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData" cloudburst:name="POSTGRES-9.2.4-RHEL-64.X64.ATF.PRB"
    cloudburst:version="1.0.0" cloudburst:build="sample" cloudburst:serviceLevel="0"
    cloudburst:description="BASEIMAGE FOR POSTGRESQL 9.2.4" cloudburst:symbolicName="POSTGRES-9.2.4-RHEL-64.X64.ATF.PRB">
  (...)

  <VirtualSystem ovf:id="POSTGRES-9.2.4-RHEL-64.X64.ATF.PRB.BASE">

    <Name>BASEIMAGE FOR POSTGRESQL 9.2.4</Name>

    <VirtualHardwareSection ovf:transport="iso">
      (...)
      <Item>
        <rasd:Caption>2 virtual CPUs</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:Description>Number of virtual CPUs</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>2 virtual CPUs</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>1</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceType>3</rasd:ResourceType>
        <rasd:VirtualQuantity>2</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <rasd:Caption>SCSI Controller 0</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:ElementName>SCSI Controller 0</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>8</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>lsilogic</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>6</rasd:ResourceType>
      </Item>
```

Which I want to modify by editing some `Item` tags and attributes (Already done, not shown in the XSL belo), and mainly adding a new `File` node at the end of `VirtualHardwareSection`

***XSL***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData" xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData"
xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1" 
exclude-result-prefixes="ns"  > <!-- Para que no copie el ns: y su URI en NetworkSection -->

    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>
    <!--<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>-->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Añadimos un nodo a VirtualHardwareSection --> 
    <xsl:template match="Envelope/VirtualSystem/VirtualHardwareSection">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> <!-- Copiamos lo que ya está incluido en el nodo -->
                <!-- *** Lo copia pero añade un atributo vacio: xmlns=""  -->
            <Item>                                                                                              <!-- v  Añadimos las siguientes líneas: v   -->
                <rasd:AddressOnParent>0</rasd:AddressOnParent>
                <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>true</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
                <rasd:Caption>Ethernet adapter on &quot;Network 2&quot;</rasd:Caption>
                <rasd:Connection>Network 2</rasd:Connection>
                <rasd:ElementName>eth1</rasd:ElementName>
                <rasd:InstanceID>13</rasd:InstanceID>
                <rasd:ResourceSubType>VMXNET3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
                <rasd:ResourceType>10</rasd:ResourceType>
            </Item>                                                                                             <!-- ^  Añadimos las siguientes líneas: ^   -->

        </xsl:copy>     <!-- lo unico que lo coloca al final del nodo VirtualHardwareSection, estaria bien que pudiera ponerse despues del nodo con igual ResourceType -->
    </xsl:template>
```

However, when I transform the XML using Altova XMLSpy 2013, I end up with this:

```
<Item>
    <rasd:AddressOnParent xmlns="">0</rasd:AddressOnParent>
    <rasd:AutomaticAllocation xmlns="">true</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
    <rasd:Caption xmlns="">Ethernet adapter on "Network 2"</rasd:Caption>
    <rasd:Connection xmlns="">Network 2</rasd:Connection>
    <rasd:ElementName xmlns="">eth1</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID xmlns="">13</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:ResourceSubType xmlns="">VMXNET3</rasd:ResourceSubType>
    <rasd:ResourceType xmlns="">10</rasd:ResourceType>
</Item>
```

I don't want the `xmlns=""` part to be there, just copy the nodes like the ones already there. What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your transformation with Saxon 9 HE and that does *not* add the extra namespace declarations, so this is either an oddity of XMLSpy or an artefact of some other bit of the transformation that you haven't shown in the question.  It's worth noting that in this case, as the elements in question have prefixed names and no child elements the `xmlns=""` declarations will not cause any problems for the consumer of the resulting XML (apart from it looking a bit ugly to human readers).

Does it improve matters if you remove the `xpath-default-namespace` and use a prefix instead?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the XDM result tree is exactly the same whether the redundant xmlns="" declarations are present or not. The difference is only in the serialization, and reparsing both will give the same XDM tree. I'm not sure without detailed checking whether the serialization spec permits the redundant declaration, but the fact is that the only problem with it is cosmetic.

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking so long to reply. Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I can't use another program as I don't have enough privileges to install anything. However, this extra attributes doesn't seem to affect my file, as they are not used, so I can safely ignore them. I hope other people see this answer and try it and see if that helps in their case to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @fernandopcg Fair enough.  By the way, it's wrong to refer to `xmlns="..."` as an "attribute" - it's a namespace declaration and you can't treat it as an attribute in XSLT (or any other namespace-aware XML processing tool).